# Decode string in RTF format

Tags: javascript, decode

A software encode output string that seems is RTF, how can I decode it with JS, a sample of its output is:

```
1. \tab \uc0\u1776{}\uc0\u1777{} \uc0\u8211{} \uc0\u1605{}\uc0\u1575{}\uc0\u1578{}\uc0\u1585{}\uc0\u1740{}\uc0\u1587{}\uc0\u8204{}\uc0\u1607{}\uc0\u1575{}\uc0\u1740{} \uc0\u1608{}\uc0\u1575{}\uc0\u1585{}\uc0\u1608{}\uc0\u1606{} \uc0\u1662{}\uc0\u1584{}\uc0\u1740{}\uc0\u1585{} | \uc0\u1705{}\uc0\u1604{}\uc0\u1575{}\uc0\u1587{}\uc0\u1616{} \uc0\u1583{}\uc0\u1585{}\uc0\u1587{}[\uc0\u1575{}\uc0\u1740{}\uc0\u1606{}\uc0\u1578{}\uc0\u1585{}\uc0\u1606{}\uc0\u1578{}]. [\uc0\u1575{}\uc0\u1587{}\uc0\u1578{}\uc0\u1606{}\uc0\u1575{}\uc0\u1583{} 5 \uc0\u1570{}\uc0\u1584{}\uc0\u1585{} 2012]. Available \uc0\u1575{}\uc0\u1586{}: http://kelasedars.org/?p=908
```

Comment: Before you can decode it with *any* language you're going to need to figure out what the encoding scheme is.

Comment: it looks very much like a [latex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTe ) excerpt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that could be RTF. here's an RTF parser in JS:

https://github.com/lazygyu/RTF-parser